# APK Signed with same certificate and verified, still not able to upload to Google play

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I am facing some unexpected problem while trying to upload the latest exported signed APK, earlier i was using eclipse and now i am using android studio and i have followed all steps and exported the signed apk, Also i verified both old apk last uploaded and this exported release apk and verified using below command

```
$ jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs my_application.apk
```

Both result looks same, which means the apk is signed with same certificate, Still when i try to upload to google play its showing me below error message.What else i need to do?

[image]

**Solution**

In one of the Library module inside Android Studio, Below line was existing

```
Debuggable==true
```

I Removed it, then I was able to export the APK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you remove the tag "debuggable true" from your build.gradle file?

Comment: How do you know it's there if you cant see it?

Comment: debuggable true tag is not there in the build.gradle, as i told i verified the apk and its showing all signature information same as the previous successful apk.

Comment: when I had this problem was enough to remove this tag, it could also be in Manifest.xml. (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: @MarcusMartins Thank you for the solution, even though i was checking the debuggable==true in manifest file from last day, i never checked manifest file inside one of the library module, I dont know how manifest file of library module cause the problem though, I removed it and problem is solved.Thanks a lot !